# Laravel : How to save multiple image file to database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to save multiple image files with different field in database such as `product_image`, `feature_image`, `slurp_image`. I used following controller method to save the image files

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
      $product = new Product();
      if($request->hasFile('product_image'))
                {
                    $file = Input::file('product_image');            
                    $imageName = time().'.'.$request->product_image->getClientOriginalExtension();           
                    $product->product_image = $imageName;
                    $file->move('images/', $imageName);
                }
        if($request->hasFile('feature_image'))
                {
                    $file = Input::file('feature_image');            
                    $imageName = time().'.'.$request->feature_image->getClientOriginalExtension();           
                    $product->feature_image = $imageName;
                    $file->move('images/', $imageName);
                }

        if($request->hasFile('slurp_image'))
                {
                    $file = Input::file('slurp_image');            
                    $imageName = time().'.'.$request->slurp_image->getClientOriginalExtension();           
                    $product->slurp_image = $imageName;
                    $file->move('images/', $imageName);
                }       

 //        dd($product->product_image);
 //       dd($product->feature_image);
 //      dd($product->slurp_image);
         $product->save();
    }
```

when i dd() the `$product->product_image`,`$product->feature_image`, `$product->slurp_image` i saw different different file name  , but after it stored into the database i saw same file stored into database in different different field.
anyone help to find out what could be the solution please?

Answer (score 0):

When you're uploading multiple images at once you'd be passing through an array of images.

This is what my controller function has looked like when I've done this previously.

```
public function multiple_upload() {
  // get the files
  $files = Input::file('images');
  // counting of uploaded images
  $file_count = count($files);
  // start count how many uploaded
  $uploadcount = 0;

  foreach ($files as $file) {
    $rules = array('file' => 'required'); //'required|mimes:png,gif,jpeg,txt,pdf,doc'
    $validator = Validator::make(array('file'=> $file), $rules);
    if($validator->passes()){
      $destinationPath = 'uploads'; // upload folder in public directory
      $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
      $upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
      $uploadcount ++;

      // save into database
      $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
      $entry = new Uploads();
      $entry->mime = $file->getClientMimeType();
      $entry->original_filename = $filename;
      $entry->filename = $file->getFilename().'.'.$extension;
      $entry->save();
    }
  }
  if($uploadcount == $file_count){
    Session::flash('success', 'Upload successfully');
    return Redirect::to('upload');
  } else {
    return Redirect::to('upload')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
  }
}
```

In your example, I'd image it would be more like this

```
       $product = new Product();


    //upload multiple files 
    $files= [];

    if($request->file('leftimage'))   $files[] = $request->file('leftimage');
    if($request->file('Middleimage')) $files[] = $request->file('Middleimage');
    if($request->file('Rightimage'))  $files[] = $request->file('Rightimage');

      foreach($files as $file)
      {
         if(!empty($file))
         {
            $filename[] = $file->getClientOrginalName();
            if(isset($filename)){
            $file->move(base_path().'/frontend/sidimage/',end($filename));
       }
   }
    $product->image1 = $filename[0];
    $product->image2 = $filename[1];
    $product->image3 = $filename[2];
```

Comment: when i implement your solution in controller i got the following Error :
`ErrorException in File.php line 131:
strrpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Comment: Is your code on github? I can have a look at it shortly for you. 

Otherwise I'll get the code working for you on here when I have more time soon

Comment: https://pastebin.com/rRYyTUBa

Patebin where i have put the controller code